# Can't import @google/pubsub and other @google npm module in Node.js 13.6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on iot project and i need to use the @google-cloud/pubsub npm module in my app.js file! I'd like use Node.js 13.6.0 as Node.js version with the ECMAScript modules!

```
// TypeError: PubSub is not a constructor 
import PubSub from '@google-cloud/pubsub';

// SyntaxError: module does not provide an export name 'PubSub'
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub';

// ReferenceError: require is not defined 
const PubSub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to import PubSub using the first approach, with Node.js 13.6.0:

```
// app.js
import PubSub from '@google-cloud/pubsub';
console.log(PubSub);

// Output
$ node app.js 
(node:17508) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{
  v1: {
    PublisherClient: [Function: PublisherClient],
    SubscriberClient: [Function: SubscriberClient]
  },
  IAM: [Function: IAM],
  PubSub: [Function: PubSub],
  Snapshot: [Function: Snapshot],
  Message: [Function: Message],
  Subscription: [Function: Subscription],
  Topic: [Function: Topic]
}
```

Did you install the Node.js Cloud Pub/Sub client library?

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/pubsub
```

Comment: Yes.... Did you try to instantiate and use the Publisher Client ?

Comment: Yes, following this example and using the PublisherClient to create a topic works for me: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.18.x/v1.PublisherClient#example Are you having trouble in importing the module or in using the PublisherClient?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i'm using:

```
'use strict';
// Google Cloud PubSub  
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
```